# Grep words with special symbols

Tags: linux, grep, special-characters

How do I grep this? (Including the special characters)

```
"Limit reached."[\n]"
```

I tried back-slashing the special symbols but end up not working, like this:

```
grep '\"Limit reached\.\"\[\\n\]\" '
```

I also tried other techniques but also not working. Is there any other syntax you could suggest/advice?

Comment: is space after last double quote a typos ?

Comment: No, but I also tried with no space

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use -F in grep

```
$ cat test.txt
"Limit reached."[\n]"
test
"Limit reached."[\n]"

$ grep -F '"Limit reached."[\n]"' test.txt
"Limit reached."[\n]"
"Limit reached."[\n]"
```

As per Manual page,

> ```
>    -F, --fixed-strings, --fixed-regexp
>           Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by> POSIX,
>  --fixed-regexp is an obsoleted alias, please do not use it new scripts.)
> ```

Comment: There is also the `fgrep` command, which as per the manpage does just `grep -F`. Personally I always use `fgrep` unless I know I am really using a regexp.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen it might be a good idea to get used to `grep -F` since `fgrep` and `egrep` are only included for backwards compatibility now that [POSIX specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) `-F` and `-E`.

Answer (score 5):

You were very close.

You do not need to excape `"`, and cannot use shell-escape in single quotes. Therefore all escaping is for grep, not for the shell. (Note on single quotes: single quotes does **no interpretation**. If you need to put a single quote withing a single quoted string, then you have to come out of single quotes e.g. `'don'\''t'` )

## Test

```
printf "%s" '"Limit reached."[\n]"' | grep  '"Limit reached\."\[\\n\]"'
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This works also but on the real logs file, doesn't work. Good explanation though.